# Travis CI failing on with Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular5, travis-ci, angular-material2

I'm unable to get my travis ci build to pass. This is my first time using Travis and Angular 5 but I've read the docs and still cant seem to figure out what I'm missing, pretty sure it's something simple. `ng build` passes locally and only fails in the build. I'm thinking some how I'm not including angular material in my build but can't find anything on google about needing to include it or how to include it. I've included the .travis.yml and the error stack, any help is appreciated.

**Build Error:**
`ERROR in ./src/styles.css
Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/src'
    at onError (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at /home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
 @ multi ./src/styles.css
ERROR in ./src/styles.css
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/src'
    at onError (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at /home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
    at runLoaders (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at /home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.catch (/home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js:198:71)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
 @ ./src/styles.css
 @ multi ./src/styles.css
ERROR in app/material.module.ts(5,15): Error during template compile of 'MaterialModule'
  Could not resolve @angular/material relative to /home/travis/build/jearl4/portfolio/src/app/material.module.ts..
src/app/material.module.ts(3,51): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/material'.`

**.travis.yml**

```
sudo: required  
dist: trusty

language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6.9"

before_install:  
 - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
 - export DISPLAY=:99.0 
 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
 - sudo apt-get update
 - sudo apt-get install -y libappindicator1 fonts-liberation
 - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome- 
stable_current_amd64.deb
 - sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb

before_script:
  - npm install -g firebase-tools
  - npm install -g @angular/cli

script:
  - ng build --prod

after_success:
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN

notifications:
  email:
    on_failure: change
    on_success: change
```

Comment: build is unable to find angular-material theme added in style.css have you installed angular-material properly?

Comment: "@angular/material" is this part of the dependencies in your package.json?

Comment: You say it works locally. Delete `node_modules`, kill any local changes, run `npm install` and say that again

Comment: I was missing angular/materials in my package, swear it was in there earlier but must have been deleted at some point. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed project modules installation. Try to add line below to your before_script section:

```
- npm install
```

If you have correct dependencies in package.json it will be installed automatically, if not then you need to add angular-material and its dependencies to your package.json. It can be done by running command below:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

Don't forget to commit your changes into your repository.

Comment: Thanks that did it. Turns out I didn't have angular material in my package, swear it was in there earlier. Thanks for the quick answer.